# how to install APC cache on aws beanstalk?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to install Alternative PHP Cache(APC) on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Please share me any idea or tutorial for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

(I am not specifically aware about the APC and PHP)

But, anything doable via commandline can be  configured in Elastic Beanstalk. Each time an instance is lanunched, these are executed and so you can practically do any kind of configuration. This adds a lot to the power of Beanstalk.

Read more here:
[Customizing and Configuring AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.htm)

Comment: Updated documentation link here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-packages

Answer (score 0):

There is an article here regarding this:

http://qpleple.com/install-apc-on-elastic-beanstalk/

Whether it works or not is not something I have finished verifying as of yet.

However using the `.ebextensions` paradigm seems to be the correct way of going about it:

```
# .ebextensions/myapp.config
packages:
  yum:
    php55-pecl-apc: []
```

EDIT:

Anyone coming from google - the new package version is `php71-pecl-apcu`

```
# .ebextensions/myapp.config
packages:
  yum:
    php71-pecl-apcu: []
```